# Why L2TP is required over IPSec

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

IPsec facilitates encryption and authentication with ESP. With tunnel mode, IPSec is also providing *tunnelling*. More importantly, one can use IPsec in tunnel mode, along with transport mode (i.e. encapsulate one over other).

Hence, IPsec is enough for:

- Authentication
- Confidentiality
- Integrity

Whereas, Layer two Tunnelling Protocol (**L2TP**) is meant only for tunnelling. Then, for encryption, it uses IPsec.

My question is why IPsec has to support L2TP  (kind of *self-respect*), where IPsec is capable of both encryption and tunnelling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what kind of tunnel you want.

IPsec can create a tunnel working at IP level for you. It means your tunnel will encapsulate IP packets, it can also be seen as a router or a layer 3 tunnel.

But you may want to have a layer 2 tunnel, a bridge, working at ethernet or another physical/liaison protocol. In this case you'll need L2TP and IPsec if you want confidentiality too because L2TP doesn't do encryption as you said.

Comment: Thanks! Are you saying that IPsec works on network layer, but L2TP works at data-link layer?

Comment: It's more a question of what's on the tunneling protocol. With ipsec you can transport IP, with L2TP, you can transport a data-link protocol.